# React Dropdown in Form From Existing Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a dropdown list in a `Form` using React and an existing array.

This is my team array:

```
const teams = [
  {name: 'Arsenal', icon: arsenal, id: 1},
  {name: 'Aston Villa', icon: villa, id: 2},
  {name: 'Brighton & Hove Albion', icon: brighton, id: 4}
]
```

And now I have a `Builder.js`, which returns several `Form.Row`:

```
const StyledInput = styled(Form.Control)`
  padding: 2px 5px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 50px;
`;


export default function Builder(){


  const [teamA, setTeamA] = useState("Arsenal");
  const [start, setStart] = useState("");
  const [end, setEnd] = useState("");

  return(

      <Form>

        <Form.Row>
          <Form.Group controlId="startDate" bssize="large">
            <Form.Label>Start Date</Form.Label>
            <StyledInput
              size="sm"
              required
              type="date"
              value={start}
              onChange={(e) => setStart(e.target.value)}
              className="smaller-input"
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group controlId="endDate" bssize="large">
            <Form.Label>End Date</Form.Label>
            <StyledInput
              size="sm"
              required
              type="date"
              value={end}
              onChange={(e) => setEnd(e.target.value)}
              className="smaller-input"
            />
          </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>

        <Form.Row>
          <Form.Group controlId="teamA" bssize="large">
           <Form.Label>Team A</Form.Label> <br />
            <StyledInput
              as="select"
              required
              className="smaller-input"
              value={teamA}
              onChange={(e) => {
                setTeamA(teams[e-1].name);
              }}
            >
              <option>{teams[0].name}</option>
            </StyledInput>
          </Form.Group>
        </Form.Row>

        <Button type="submit">Create</Button>
      </Form>
     );
}
```

However the dropdown list in this case just shows the first team, Arsenal. Eventually I would like to extend this to 20+ teams, so I would rather not declare them one by one in a `Dropdown.Item` again. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using this map method:

```
<StyledInput
   as="select"
   required
   className="smaller-input"
   value={teamA}
   onChange={(e) => {
     setTeamA(teams[e-1].name);
   }}
>
  {
    teams.map((team) => {
      return <option>{team.name}</option>
    })
  }
</StyledInput>
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't explain the question well enough. I'll update the code, it actually returns a few `Form.Row` , and this was just one of them...

Comment: I've updated the code... hope this makes more sense. Sorry for the lack of clarity initially.